# how to use the new ntfs3 driver on fedora 34

Tags: fedora, ntfs

linux kernel 5.15 comes with new ntfs3 driver, I'm on fedora 34 with kernel 5.15.6, but when I mount a device using ntfs3, it reports error:

```
# uname -a
Linux fedora 5.15.6-100.fc34.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 1 13:41:51 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# mount -t ntfs3 /dev/sda1 /run/media/sify/Elements\ SE
mount: /run/media/sify/Elements SE: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

do I need to do anything special to use the new ntfs3 driver?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by repairing the hard disk on windows using `chkdisk`, it took a whole day and I lost some data. But after that, I can mount the disk using ntfs3. I suspect I've saved some malformed data on that disk before.